# User.IsInRole() work in MVC C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using

```
If(User.IsInRole("member"))
{

}
```

but not able to get it to work in C# MVC class. Note that I am not using it in a controller which I am able to get working. What am I missing? The code does not even recognize what User is.

I think it may be a namespace but I have used the `.Mvc` namespace as well as other..

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "*not able to get it to work*"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current.User` instead

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` isn't available inside a Controller. You can just use `HttpContext`.

Comment: The OP did say that he wasn't using this inside a controller

Comment: Ahhh you are correct, I misread him, and your answer is correct as well!

Comment: What about unit testing of this code in isolation? What about the Single Responsibility Principle?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it (it's correct in terms coupling but it's violating the single responsibility principle):

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("member"))
{

}
```

Basically here you are using the [`Roles.IsUserInRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx) static method which in turn is using the role provider you have configured in the `<roles>` section of your web.config to get the roles of the currently authenticated user.

But that's not the approach I would recommend you undertaking. Things like Roles and Membership providers should are specific to your Web Layer. Your business classes shouldn't be bothered to be retrieving this information. This information should be passed as parameter to them.

For example if all methods of this class required this information you could have simply have used constructor injection:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly bool _isCurrentUserAMember;
    public MyClass(bool isCurrentUserAMember)
    {
        _isCurrentUserAMember = isCurrentUserAMember;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (_isCurrentUserAMember)
        {
            // do some business logic for members
        }
        else
        {
            // do some other business logic for non-members
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here what this class cares is whether the current user is a member in order to perform his business logic, right? This class doesn't care how to fetch this information. It's not its responsibility and if you start fetching it from within the class you are violating the Single Responsibility Principle which is very important because now your class is doing 2 things: retrieving the roles information and doing the business logic.

With my recommended approach we have inverted this responsibility to the calling code, which usually in those kind of scenarios happens to be an MVC controller, which could query the role provider as shown in my first example and pass it to the underlying class.

If this class had more methods and the other methods didn't require this information you could also have passed the boolean parameter as argument to the method instead of using constructor injection.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect descriptions. May you please reference me to find out more about Single Responsibility Principle?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("yourRole")`

Comment: Explain your answer

Comment: If you want to use User in c# class, just use 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("yourRole")
* yourRole: put your desired Role