# Implementing logic to provide role based viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been thinking about this for the past few days and was wondering what everyone else's take is on it. I want to implement some content that is based on what role the user belongs to. Our applications uses HTTP headers to receive role information. In MVC should I have the controller handle the role detection, and then pass a boolean value into the viewmodel.

Viewmodel:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product MyProduct { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuperAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Info()
    {
        //get product information here

        ProductViewModel pvm = new pvm();
        pvm.Product = theProduct;
        pvm.IsAdmin = checkAdminAccess(); //This would return a bool if they had access
        pvm.IsSuperAdmin = checkSuperAdminAccess();//This would return a bool if they had access

        return View(pvm);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@if(Model.IsAdmin == true || Model.IsSuperAdmin == true)
{
    //Render Content for admin (Either directly or via Partial View)
}
@if(Model.IsSuperAdmin == true)
{
    //Render Superadmin content (Either directly or via Partial View)
}
//Implement other Product Stuff Here
```

Or would it be better to create a partial view and handle the logic in the view. This seems like there is less work involved.

```
@if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("role")){
    ViewBag.Role = Request.Headers["role"].ToString();
}
...
@if(ViewBag.Role == "Admin" || ViewBag.Role == "SuperAdmin")
{
    @Html.Partial("AdminPartial")//Or Render Code Directly?
    if(ViewBag.Role == "SuperAdmin")
    {
        @Html.Partial("SuperAdminPartial")//Or Render Code Directly?
    }
}
//Implement other Product Stuff Here
```

Is there any added benefits to doing it one way or another, should I be rendering the content directly or using a partial view or does it not matter? Or am I missing some other way that this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AuthorizeAttribute to restrict access/use of controller actions:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Customer")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Info()
    {
        //get product information here

        ProductViewModel pvm = new pvm();

        return View(pvm);
    }

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult EditInfo()
    {
        //get product information here

        EditProductViewModel epvm = new epvm();

        return View(epvm);
    }
}
```

This is the most basic way to restrict access by callers to an action method. However, with a large application with many roles/controllers/actions, annotating and keeping track of all attributes can become difficult.

There is product called [Fluent Security](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/) that allows security to be specified in a central place, and gets rid of the issue mentioned previously.

There is also the issue of the single responsibility principle, look at [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259063/user-isinrole-work-in-mvc-c-sharp-class/14259214#14259214) to this question - he explains it quite well.